# jQuery AJAX - receive multiple data

Tags: jquery, ajax

I use Wordpress, PHP, jQuery and AJAX.

I can get data from PHP through an AJAX call, like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo get_bloginfo('url'); ?>/?addmod_ajax=1",
    data: "action=load&type=part",
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

When I have received the data I also want to know how it went. The "data" contains HTML and I also want error codes like "success" or "not-found".

How do I solve it the best way?

**Wordpress**

Because I use Wordpress I need to call a AJAX trigger (in the url). If I could keep that intact it would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo get_bloginfo('url'); ?>/?addmod_ajax=1",
    data: "action=load&type=part",
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    },
    failure: function(){
        alert('failed');
    }
});
```

You could add a failure handler to see if the ajax request is failed, but other than that, if want a different return value, you will have to change the result of the function you are calling on the backend, or create a new similar function that instead of just returning the html, returns a json encoded array with the first element being found or not found, and the second element being the html.

Edit: Appended comment to complete answer and format code.

at the place where you echo 'your result', you can echo instead

```
json_encode(array('success'=>true,'html'=>$yourData));
```

and in your ajax call, add

```
 dataType:'json'
```

then you can access the success and html values in your success handler.

Comment: Is it possible to use jSON and still keep my "url" like it is now? If you know how it's done, feel free to update your post with it.

Thanks so far!

Comment: @Jens - Yes, do you know where the function is on the PHP side that you are calling?

Comment: Where? If you mean a URL it's here http://localhost/concepts/addmod/?ajax_trigger=1. If you mean a function it could call... function load_part() { echo 'My result'; }

Comment: at the place where you echo 'your result', you can echo instead json_encode(array('success'=>true,'html'=>$yourData)); , and in your ajax call, add dataType:'json', then you can access the success and html values in your success handler.

Comment: Thanks! Can you edit your answer with that info? Then I will accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I usually just return an array or dict with one value designated as the state.

```
$.get(url,data,function(data) {
    if (data[0]=='parseError') { //could also be data.state
         $("#formError").html("You have entered an invalid value.").show();
    }
    else if (data[0]=='permissionDenied') {
        $("#formError").html("You do not have permission to edit this.").show();
    }
    else {
        $("#formSuccess").html("Your changes have been saved");
    }
});
```

Those examples may not be the best (permission denied and parsing errors could be handled on the front end). Still the concept is solid.